# Can I upload a package to Octopus from linux using curl without using NuGet or PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, curl, nuget, octopus-deploy

We're building a package with Jenkins on a linux slave, and want to upload the package to an Octopus instance, but we don't have access to Nuget or Powershell on the linux box.

The Octopus examples say you can do this by

```
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.UploadFile("http://octopus.example.com/api/packages/raw?apiKey=<Your API Key>", "YourApp.1.0.0.zip")
```

Can I do this with curl?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the following is the curl equivalent.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Octopus-ApiKey: <Your API Key>" \
-F "file=@\"YourApp.1.0.0.zip\";filename=\"YourApp.1.0.0.zip\";type=application/zip" \
http://octopus.example.com/api/packages/raw?replace=true
```